# How to stop setEmptyView displaying a TextView while populating a ListView with Android?

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

In my MainActivty i'm displaying a list of items, from a Firebase database using a FirebaseListAdapter like this:

```
firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, String.class, R.layout.list, ref) {
@Override
protected void populateView(final View v, final String listName, int position) {
       ((TextView )v.findViewById(R.id.list_name)).setText(listName);
    }
};
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
listView.setAdapter(firebaseListAdapter);

TextView emptyView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
listView.setEmptyView(emptyView);
```

The problem is, when the activity starts, the `emptyView` is displayed even if i have data in my adapter. This is happening for a short time, while the `ListView` is populated and than disappears. How can i stop this from happening? As you you can see, i have set `listView.setEmptyView(emptyView);` after i have set the `firebaseListAdapter` but no luck. This is how my .xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/empty_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Like you said the empty view does not disappear until the list is populated, thats how the empty view works

Comment: Thanks for the answer but do you have any idea, to solve this problem?

Comment: dont use the empty view and handle showing it yourself

Comment: Ok, but using a condition based on what? I'm using firebaseListAdapter.getCount() == 0 but it's not working

Comment: Do you need to call notifydatasetchanged for you firebaseListAdapter? I have a problem with recyclverview and normal adapter and I solved by calling `TextView emptyView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
listView.setEmptyView(emptyView);` after `listView.notifydatasetchanged;`, not after initialial adapter.

Comment: @RoShanShan No, i don't need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. I need this `empty_view` not to be displayed while the `ListView` is populated. Only when the database has no records. Thanks

Comment: Your `firebaseListAdapter` automatically call `notifyDataSetChanged()` when having changed in your data?

Comment: Yes, `firebaseListAdapter` automatically calls notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: The codes quite long, cannot comment here. You can see the answer below.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139273/discussion-between-alex-m-and-roshan-shan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your adapter has this method, you can set empty view in this method,

```
adapter.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {

            @Override
            public void onChanged() {
                super.onChanged();

              TextView emptyView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
               listView.setEmptyView(emptyView);

            }
        });
```

Comment: Working like a charm! Thank you so much!